# Ignite compute broadcast closure - class not found exception

Tags: ignite

The code `final Collection<Long> result = ignite.compute(group).broadcast(() -> 42L);`

Throws an exception about not being to find the lambda's declaring class. What am I missing?

package com.example;

class IgniteSandbox() {
    ...

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    ...
    final Collection<Long> result = ignite.compute(group).broadcast(() -> 42L);
}
```

}

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.IgniteSandbox
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.forName(IgniteUtils.java:8608)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClass(MarshallerContextImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:688)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: com.example.IgniteSandbox
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForTypeId(BinaryContext.java:697)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadClass(BinaryUtils.java:1631)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadClass(BinaryUtils.java:1568)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadClass(BinaryUtils.java:1545)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readClass(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.readFixedType(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:902)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.read0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:698)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:183)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to read field [name=capturingClass]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:187)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:870)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to deserialize object [typeName=java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:909)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1762)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryUtils.doReadObject(BinaryUtils.java:1793)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.readObject(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1329)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.readBinary(GridClosureProcessor.java:1872)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:860)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to deserialize object [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:909)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1762)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1714)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:310)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:99)
    at org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9962)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to deserialize object [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:9968)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.initialize(GridJobWorker.java:440)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to deserialize object [typeName=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.initialize(GridJobWorker.java:459)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1117)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1921)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1556)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1184)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:125)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1091)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable `peerClassLoading`?

If not, you should have `com.example.IgniteSandbox` class with all dependencies on all nodes participating in computation.

Comment: Peer class loading is disabled. Must be that. Thanks.